# Python Socket Return Ping Answer to Client

Tags: python, sockets

I'm struggling with getting reply back to client when pinging through socket server.

Trying to create something simple, where I can ping servers from client through socket server.

Client checks that socket server is online, socket server in "server" will respond status. Client sends the ping command to socket server, socket server initiate the ping to where ever. Raw printout will be sent to client.

What's the best way to do it?

First time working with sockets.

Server

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import socket
import sys

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 8085

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print('Socket created')

# Bind socket
try:
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
        print('Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1])
        sys.exit()

print('Socket bind complete')

#Start listening on socket
s.listen(10)
print('Socket now listening')

# Talk with client
while 1:
    #wait to accept a connection - blocking call
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print('Connected')
        
        while True:
                dataFromClient = conn.recv(1024)
                print(dataFromClient.decode('utf-8'))
                if not dataFromClient:
                        print("[Client] Disconnected")
                        break
        conn.sendall(dataFromClient)
s.close()
```

Client

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import socket
import subprocess
import os

SERVER = "127.0.0.1"

clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket.connect((SERVER,8085))


os.system("clear")
os.system("cls")

while True:
        data = input("Input: ")
        clientSocket.send(data.encode())
#       dataFromServer = clientSocket.recv(1024)
#       print(dataFromServer.decode())
        if data == "ping":
                input1 = str(input("Enter command: "))
                with subprocess.Popen(input1,shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE) as proc:
                        for line in proc.stdout:
                                clientSocket.send(line)
                                print(proc.communicate())

        elif data == "help":
                print("Command: pingdl,destip=<isp>,repeat=<amount>")
clientSocket.close()
```

Comment: I don't see any code in the server that sends status or initiates a ping. The client seems to be doing the ping itself with `subprocess.Popen()`.

Comment: `conn.sendall(dataFromClient)` will never send anything, because it happens after the loop, which exits when `dataFromClient` is empty.

Comment: I forgot to remove that line, I've updated the client code now. I also added `print(proc.commincation)` after `clientSocket.send(line)`, that's some way to go forward with this.

Comment: The problem description is incomprehensible. Whose _reply_? What's meant by _pinging through socket server_? Which _servers_? Where _socket server in "server" will respond_ which _status_? Where does _socket server initiate the ping_? Where is _where ever_? Which _printout_? What's the first behavioral deviation of your programs from the expectation?